# Appending to relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pycharm

Given a simple one to many relationship where one page can be linked to multiple errors:

```
class Page(Base):
    ...
    errors = relationship('Error', back_populates='page')

class Error(Base):
    ...
    page = relationship('Page', back_populates='errors')
```

I add error objects to a page object simple by

```
page.errors.append(error)
```

This works. However PyCharm warns about Error would have no reference "append". 
My Question: Is this just PyCharm not understanding that Page.errors is of type list(?) and not Error or is is there something I should do better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone stumbles upon the same problem: I did not notify any problems yet and so I guess it is simply pycharm not recognising the type correctly. You can simple help it by using type hints:

```
class Page(Base):
    ...
    errors: list = relationship('Error', back_populates='page')
```